# hide span class on visited link

Tags: html

I want to display a span class along with the link, for example

```
<a href="#">New entries<span class="number">1</span></a>
```

But as the link is visited, i want to remove the span class from the link, and only want to display:

```
<a href="#">New entries</a>
```

How can I do this by any simple approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript try adding a click event to the A element, finding the SPAN element from it's children and then destroying it - like (pseudo-jQuery):

```
$("A").click(function (e) {
    var span = $(this).children("SPAN");
    if (span.length < 1) { return; }
    span[0].remove()
});
```

With pure CSS, you could simply do:

```
A:visited SPAN { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it works perfectly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a:hover span { display: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#">New entries<span class="number">1</span></a>
    </body>
</html>
```